# How do I refer to a cell in another worksheet with a long name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As explained in this other [Answer](https://superuser.com/a/419034/269574), `SheetName!A1` = cell A1 in the worksheet called "SheetName" (without quotations).

Say the name for my worksheet is very long. Without shortening "SheetName" and writing out expressly "SheetName", what's a more efficient way to refer to it? Is it possible to designaet "SheetName" by "S" and then input `S!A1`?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible in a formula. If you have a long sheet name, wrap it in single quotes -

`'this sheet name is huge'!A1`

Answer (score 1):

You can create **named ranges** in Excel, which are like aliases.

If you select a single cell or a range of cells, go to the text box to the left of the formula bar. By default, it will display the generic name of the currently selected cell, such as `C5`. However, you can type a simple name into this box and press enter to give the cell a name, and then use that name in formulas.

For example, you can go to cell A1 on Sheet1, and name it "Profits". Then on Sheet2, you can specify B3 to be `=Profits*2`, and then `Sheet2!B3` will always have twice the value of `Sheet1!A1`

Comment: This would be a very clever way around the restriction if you don't need your range to be dynamic. +1